# Find solution of stochastic differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I need to solve this system of stochastic differential equations:
$$\begin{cases}
dX_1(t)=dt+dW_1(t),  \\[2ex]
dX_2(t)=X_1(t)dW_2(t), 
\end{cases}$$ 
where $W_1(t), W_2(t)$ are independent Wiener processes.
From the first equation I found:
$$X_1(t) = t + W_1(t)$$
Then, I substituted $X_1(t)$ in the second equation:
$$dX_2(t)=(t+W_1(t))dW_2(t)=tdW_2+W_1(t)dW_2(t)$$
And I'm stuck on this step. I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: It's better to use MathJax to type formulae instead of using pictures since pictures are unsearchable.

Comment: @Saad Agree. Fixed it.

Comment: You already have the solution: $X_1(t) = t +W_1(t)$ and $X_2(t) = \int_0^t (s +W_1(s))\, dW_2(s)$.

Comment: @Michh Thanks for the comment. So we can’t find this integral for $X_2(t)$ ?

Comment: No but this is already explicit! Quick note: you still have to take into account the initial condition. This solution corresponds to $X_1(0) = X_2(0) = 0$.

Comment: @Michh many thanks

Comment: @Michh Does that mean that the solution above isn't a solution because the problem doesn't state $X_1(0)=X_2(0)=0$?

Comment: @RadialArmSaw - it is *a* solution to the the problem, you just cannot call it *the* solution. It is one particular solution, but if the initial conditions are neither provided nor implied, then you should seek a general solution.

Comment: @GlenO  The general solution is an indefinite integral, correct?  $$X_{2}(t)=\int{\left[t+W_{1}(t)\right]}dW_{2}(t)$$

Comment: @RadialArmSaw - in a manner of speaking. More accurately, it should be expressed as a definite integral plus a constant of integration. Also, you need to handle the constant of integration for $X_1$, too.

Comment: @GlenO Isn't an indefinite integral equal to the sum of a definite integral and a constant of integration?  So wouldn't both be correct?

Comment: @RadialArmSaw - again, in a manner of speaking. The problem with writing it as an indefinite integral is that you can't determine the constant of integration because it's not explicitly written. While it could be called a general solution when written as an indefinite integral, if you write it as $X_2(t)=\int_0^t [t'+W_1(t')]\ dW_2(t') + C$, then if you know $X_2(0)$, you immediately know $C$. (excuse the slight abuse of notation, here, as strictly the integral isn't over $t$)

Comment: @GlenO oh I see.  Thanks for clarifying.